# What is the difference between "job" and "work"?

Tags: meaning, differences

When is it better to use "job" and when "work"? For instance I am writing text on the logo saying "Still do your job manually? Then ask us to help you." Is it correct to use "job" here or "work" is more suitable one? Why?

What is the general rule of using these two words?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Work" [means:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/work)

> exertion or effort directed to produce or accomplish something; labor; toil.
>   Example: Mowing the lawn is work

["Job"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/job) however, means paid work:

> a piece of work, especially a specific task done as part of the routine of one's occupation or for an agreed price:
>   Example: My job is cleaning the university toilets.

We "work" at our "jobs", and "work" can be used to refer to our "jobs", but the underlying difference is, "work" can be used in areas where its just labour, while "job" refers specifically to paid work.

Comment: So, which one should I pick for logo?

Comment: It depends what your logo is

Comment: I would say "work" would be better in most cases, because it includes more.

Comment: Well, "job" is not always paid. "I have a job for you" might be said by an organizer to someone who is just doing unpaid chores, like for family or as part of volunteer service.